# Cleaning Bricklink pieces bought as "new"

Tags: piece-information, cleaning, bricklink

I'm just preparing my first Bricklink order and I've got a simple question - Is there a reason to clean pieces bought on Bricklink which were sold as "new"?

Comment: Pieces sold as new are directly pulled from brand new LEGO sets, or from the Pick-A-Brick wall. I don't see what would be the point of cleaning them. They are as new as new and clean as they can get.

Comment: @TheBrickBlogger: To be fair, pieces from the PAB wall that have been in there for a long time may well be as good as used, thanks to dozens or possibly hundreds of hands rummaging through them, dust, shelf wear and all that. I can no longer guarantee pieces on the PAB wall to be new - it seems to be a crapshoot these days unless I keep track of what's been on a particular wall and what's recently changed.

Answer (score 3):

No. 10 out of 10 orders were in perfect condition. Cleaning the bricks would have been a waste of time, and would have added unneccessary scratches.